# how to hide the content in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I am working with sitecore and now i needs to hide some of the content item in sitcore.what is the process to hide the content'

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to hide and what do you want to hide?

You could probably setup security to only allow people with certain roles to read, write, etc certain items (and subitems) or setup that only certain roles can see certain fields.

You can probably find most of what you need here:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20Administrator%20Cookbook.aspx

Otherwise give an example of what you want to do, it might be easier to help then.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to hide from a role or a user, you can setup permissions accordingly to do so. Please specify the requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not exactly what you need, but it's not really clear. You can hide items from regular (= non-admin) users by setting the checkbox `Hidden` as such, which can be found in the `Appearance` section of your item. When hidden, your items will be displayed in grey and italic in the item tree for administrators, and totally non-visible to users. Note that if you cannot find the section, you need to enable the `Standard Fields` under `View` in the ribbon.

Of course this field is also accessible via the API by any of these two means:

```cs
item.Appearance.Hidden = true; // Or false.
item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Hidden] = "1"; // Or string.Empty.
```

Comment: 'Hide Item' on the 'Configure' tab is a nice shortcut

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Hide items from non admin users by using 'Hide Item' button in configure ribbon.

Protect items from non admin users by using 'Protect Item' button in configure ribbon.